# DatabaseMetataData does not see a table

Tags: java, oracle11g

I use oracle 11g with hibernate. Hibernate is configured to validate schema on startup, however for some reason it can not find one table and fails.

I have a strange situation where `java.sql.DatabaseMetaData` does not see one table (`getTables` returns empty result set) when it sees other table from the same schema.

So I have following situation:

```
String[] TYPES = {"TABLE", "VIEW"};
DatabaseMetaData meta = ...
meta.getTables(null, "SCHEMA_NAME", "TABLE1", TYPES).next(); // true
meta.getTables(null, "SCHEMA_NAME", "TABLE2", TYPES).next(); // false
```

But following queries are successfully executed:

```
select * from schemaName.table1
select * from schemaName.table2
```

More I can query a dictionary table and see both these tables:

```
select * from user_tables where table_name in ('TABLE1', 'TABLE2')
```

What could be a reason?

Comment: Is it a synonym, or is the table name actually `TABLE2` (`getTables` requires that the case is an exact match)?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, that is not a synonym, I can see that table in `USER_TABLES`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DatabaseMetaData md = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
while (rs.next()) {
  System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
}
```

try the above code

The column 3 represents the Table_name
Click to know all the column [numbers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

Comment: Answers only containing code are useless for anyone else with a similar, but not exactly the same, problem reading this question. Therefore, it is not useful on SO.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Hope it will be useful now

Comment: I checked if table is visible with this connection, it is. That is strange, why then it is not visible in application?

Comment: @michaelnesterenko is it helpful to you?

Comment: @michaelnesterenko What is the exact value shown for that table, because case of tablename matters for `getTables`.

Comment: Oh my, I found the cause. It is because databases are different. I should have checked that first, but I was sure I use same databases.